# url cleaning not working using urlRewriteFIlter

Tags: java, jsp, url-rewriting, filter, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

```
 <rule>
            <from>/admin/index/index.jsp</from>
            <to>/admin/index</to>
 </rule>





<outbound-rule>

        <from>/admin/index</from>
        <to>/admin/index/index.jsp</to>

    </outbound-rule>
```

I am trying to rewrite this url "/admin/index/index.jsp" to "/admin/index"..but i guess it is redirecting it to "/admin/index" because it says resource could not be found so whats the problem i just want to write "/admin/index/index.jsp" as "/admin/index"

Answer (score 0):

Use rule as

```
<rule>
    <from>/admin/index</from>
     <to>/admin/index/index.jsp</to>
</rule>
```

Now use path+"/admin/index+ in href tag or where you want to specify url
Where path is

String path  = request.getContextPath();

It will work